# .htaccess error hard to find ...

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

**Code**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Domain re-direction
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stackexchange\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.stackexchange\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.stackexchange\.org\/“ [R=301]
#
#Support page re-direction
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^thesupport/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^thesupport/?$ https\:\/\/www\.stackexchange\.org\/support\/ [R=301]
#
#Privacy page re-direction
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^privacy/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^privacy/?$ https\:\/\/www\.stackexchange\.org\/privacy\/ [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

**Problem**:

- 301 Redirect from *stackexchange.net* to *stackexchange.org* is working
- 301 Redirect from *stackexchange.net/thesupport* to *stackexchange.org/support* is NOT working (always gives a 404 page)

No difference to problem even if %{REQUEST_URI} is replaced with either:

```
%{THE_REQUEST}
%{REQUEST_FILENAME}
%{REMOTE_URI}
```

I have gone over http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708 already but can’t seem to find where the error is coming from.

Any ideas in regards what might be wrong with my hatches code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^thesupport/?$ [NC]
```

Since `REQUEST_URI` matches a URI with leading slash. So your corrected condition should be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/thesupport/?$ [NC]
```

However looking at your rule you don't even need a condition and can handle this in `RewriteRule` itself.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Domain re-direction
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?stackexchange\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.stackexchange.org [R=301,L]

#
#Support page re-direction
RewriteRule ^thesupport/?$ https://www.stackexchange.org/support/ [R=301,L]

#
#Privacy page re-direction
RewriteRule ^privacy/?$ https://www.stackexchange.org/privacy/ [R=301,L]
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Hi, @anubhava would try out your suggestion and give feedback. Thanks

Comment: Hi @anubhava ... same problem like earlier ... problem still remains even have clearing all caches and CDN

Comment: Had no idea Wordpress could have an effect ... How does RewriteBase help with Wordpress

Comment: Your `WP` .htaccess might already have `RewriteBase` line. Can you post your complete WP .htaccess (and please don't make this comment section a long discussion board).

Answer (score 0):

Solved (@anubhava) as follows:
- used re-direction code as suggested by @anubhava
- redirection code was moved to top of .htaccess file so it comes before WordPress rewrite rules.
- RewriteBase also added to code.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Domain re-direction
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?stackexchange\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ https://www.stackexchange.org [R=301,L]

#
#Support page re-direction
RewriteRule ^thesupport/?$ https://www.stackexchange.org/support/ [R=301,L]

#
#Privacy page re-direction
RewriteRule ^privacy/?$ https://www.stackexchange.org/privacy/ [R=301,L]
</ifModule>

.
.
.

# BEGIN WordPress
```